# Chainerでアウトプットがベクトルのニューラルネットワークを訓練したい

Tags: python, 機械学習, chainer

Chainerでニューラルネットワークの勉強をしています。

今、3次元ベクトルtが教師データとして与えられています。
このtを用いて、ニューラルネットワークを訓練したいと思っています。

そこで、アウトプットが3次元ベクトルyのニューラルネットワークを作り、
教師ベクトルtとのユークリッド距離|t-y|を最小化するように訓練しようと思います。

このような場合Chainerでは、
分類や回帰で用いるsoftmax_cross_entropyやmean_squared_errorを
用いることはできないように思いました。

どのようなコードを書けば上記のような最適化が実現できるのか、
教えていただければと思います。

Comment: 三層のバックプロパゲーションNNでしょうか?出力yと教師tは良いとして、入力(Xとします）はどんなシェイプですか？tとXの関係は何でしょう？コスト関数がユークリッド距離ならmean_squared_errorそのものでは？使えないと思った理由は何でしょう？Chainerは僕もインストールしてみたばかりなので、変なことを聞いているかもしれません。

Comment: すみません、返信が遅くなりました。僕も少し勘違いしていたようで、mean_squared_errorを使ってちゃんと学習できています。Chainerだとバッチ処理が前提になっているので、ちょっと混乱してしまいました（データは「ベクトルのリストの形」で渡す必要があるのですね）。